# Laravel case sensitive search

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello I want WATER return when searches for water
this is my code But it doesn't work

```
$value = "water";
$categories = Category::where(DB::raw('LOWER(`title`)'), 'like', '%' . Str::lower($value) . '%')->get();
```

Do you have a solution for searching with capital letters?

Comment: What is the definition of the column, and the character set/collation of the table?

Comment: @aynber  varchar and utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Odd, both of those should support case insensitive searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the search to be case-sensitive and use MySQL, you can use BINARY. The BINARY keyword in MySQL makes the comparison case-sensitive.

```
$value = "water";
$categories = Category::where(DB::raw('BINARY `title`'), 'like', '%' . $value . '%')->get();
```

If you're using MySQL and want to perform a case-insensitive search, you can use the COLLATE clause in your query.

```
$value = "water";
$categories = Category::where('title', 'like', '%' . $value . '%')->collate('utf8_general_ci')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked But when I search Water doesn't return WATER .
just returns when i search water OR WATER

Comment: If you want the returned value to be capitalized as "WATER" regardless of how it's stored in the database, you can use the DB::raw function along with the UPPER function in your query.


$value = "water";
$categories = Category::where(DB::raw('UPPER(`title`)'), 'like', '%' . Str::upper($value) . '%')->get();